# Finding shotest path between Wikipedia articles

Tags: python, web-crawler, wiki, wikipedia

I am writing a python web crawler to find a path between Wikipedia articles.

I have a start article and a goal article and I am trying to find a short path between them.

Right now I am basically just doing a breadth search from the start to the goal with some code like this.

```
 for link in to_crawl:
    links = get_all_links(source(link), crawled)
    if goal in links:
        return path+[link]+[goal]
    crawled.append(link)
    to_crawl.append(links)
```

It is getting from one article to another if they are only a few degrees away, but I need a way to keep track of the path I took.

Comment: Download a [copy of the database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) instead of hammering the web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just keep track of it. Instead of having a list of links, have a list of `link, path` pairs. Something like this:

```
to_crawl = [(start_page, [])]
for link, path in to_crawl:
    links = get_all_links(source(link), crawled)
    if goal in links:
        return path+[link]+[goal]
    crawled.append(link)
    to_crawl.extend((new_link, path + [new_link]) for new_link in links)
```

Also note that you had a serious problem with your existing code: `to_crawl.append(links)` appends a list of links as if it were a single link, when obviously you wanted to append each link in that list separately. I've fixed that by using `extend`.

As a side note, `path+[link]+[goal]` is an odd thing to be returning. For example, if you went from page A to page D via path A-B-C-D, you're going to end up with B, C, D, C, D as your return value, which seems odd to say the least. If you need the last link and the goal separately from the path, why not just `return path, link, goal` instead of packing them onto the path?